# How to create a specific React or Redux state for referencing individual product quantities?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

So I have a shopping cart in my application and need to increase the quantity of X specific item in the cart, whenever I click on the `add to cart` button.

So say I have a Laptop in the cart which quantity is 1 (meaning I will buy one) and I want the quantity to go up to 2 whenever I click 'Add to cart' on the same product. I have already been able to achieve that, however, since I am keeping the quantity in the Redux store, it increases the quantity of every item in the cart at the same time.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, the 'Cantidad' (quantity in English) is 4 for every product because it comes from the same state item in Redux.

Below is the `Cart` code:

```
import { StyledButton } from './styles'
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge'
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer'
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { productReducer } from '../../store/productReducer'

export const Cart = function({quantity}) {
  const [openCart, setOpenCart] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  const { cart, total, amount } = useSelector(({productReducer}) => ({
    cart: productReducer.cart,
    total: productReducer.total,
    amount: productReducer.amount,
  }))

  // const handler = window.ePayco.checkout.configure({
  //   key: process.env.REACT_APP_EPAYCO_PUBLIC_KEY,
  //   test: true
  // })

  const data = {
    external: 'false',
    autoclick: 'false',

    amount: total,
  }
  
  const getTotalPrice = (cartItem, amount) => {
    return cartItem.reduce((ack, cv) => {
      const totalPrice = ack + (cv.price * amount)
      return totalPrice
    }, 0)
  }

  return(
    <>
      <StyledButton onClick={() => setOpenCart(true)}>
        <Badge color='error'>
          <AddShoppingCartIcon />
        </Badge>
      </StyledButton>
      <Drawer
        anchor='right'
        open={openCart}
        onClose={() => setOpenCart(false)}
      >
        <h3>Productos en tu carrito</h3>
        <p>Total de tu carrito: {getTotalPrice(cart, amount)}</p>
        {!!cart && cart.length > 0 && cart.map(product => 
          <section key={product._id} >
            <h3>Productos en tu carrito</h3>
            <img src={product.productPictures} /> 
            <p>price={product.price * amount}</p> 
            <p>prodname={product.name}</p>
            <p>Cantidad:{quantity}</p>
          </section>
        )}
      </Drawer>
    </>
  )
}
```

And here is the code for the page where I invoke the `<Cart />` and where the `handleAddToCart()` function is:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { StyledLink } from "./styles"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useHistory } from "react-router"
import { Cart } from "../../Components/Cart"
import { NavBar } from "../../Components/Navbar"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { ProductPicture } from "../../Components/ProductPicture"
import { addToCart, changeAmount, changeProducts } from "../../store/productReducer"


function useApi() {
  const { products, cart, amount, total } = useSelector(({productReducer}) => ({
    products: productReducer.products,
    total: productReducer.total,
    cart: productReducer.cart,
    amount: productReducer.amount,
  }))

  const [error, setError] = useState()
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getProducts() {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios({
          method: 'GET',
          baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL,
          url: '/products',
        })
        dispatch(changeProducts(data))
      }catch(error) {
        dispatch(setError(error))
      }
    }

    getProducts()

    return () => {
      
    }
  }, [])
  
  return { products, cart, amount, total }
  }
  
 export const HomePage = function() {
   const history = useHistory()
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   
   function handleClick(prod)  {
     history.push(`/productinfo/${prod._id}`)
   }

  const handleAddToCart = (prod, items, amount) => {
    const isItemInCart = items.find(el => el._id === prod._id)
    if(isItemInCart) {
      return dispatch(changeAmount(amount + 1))
    }
    dispatch(addToCart(prod))
    dispatch(changeAmount(amount + 1))
  }

    const { products, cart, amount } = useApi()
    return (
      <section>
        <Cart quantity={amount} />
        <NavBar />
        {!!products && products.length > 0 && products.map((prod, i) => (
          <section>
            <StyledLink onClick={() => handleClick(prod)}
            >
              <ProductPicture
                key={`chk-${i}`}
                picture={prod.productPictures}
                prodname={prod.name}
                price={prod.price}
              />
            </StyledLink>
            <button
              key={i}
              type='button'
              onClick={() => handleAddToCart(prod, cart, amount)}
            >
              Agregar al carrito
            </button>
          </section>
        ))}
      </section>
    )
}
```

EDIT: As per advice, I am adding the `reducer` code below:

```
const CHANGE_PRODUCTS = 'CHANGE_PRODUCTS'
const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
const CHANGE_AMOUNT = 'CHANGE_AMOUNT'
const CHANGE_TOTAL = 'CHANGE_TOTAL'

export function changeTotal(value) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_TOTAL,
    payload: value,
  }
}

export function changeAmount(value) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_AMOUNT,
    payload: value,
  }
}

export function changeProducts(value) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_PRODUCTS,
    payload: value,
  }
}

export function addToCart(value) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: value,
  }
}
const initialSate = {
  products: {},
  cart: [],
  amount: 0,
  total: 0,
}

export function productReducer(state = initialSate, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHANGE_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      }
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [
          ...state.cart,
          action.payload
        ]
      }
    case CHANGE_AMOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        amount: action.payload,
      }
    case CHANGE_TOTAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        total: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So what I need to know is any ideas on how to make that `Quantity` state item individual so that it changes based on which product you add to the `Cart`.

Comment: You should just dispatch the `addToCart` action with the product and handle either adding the item to the cart or simply incrementing its quantity in state if it's already in the cart. Can you add your reducer code to your question? If you insist on a `changeAmount` action then it should probably also consume a product id so you can identify what specific product needs quantity updated.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comments :D. I am adding the reducer code now.

Comment: I don't insist on the `changeAmount` action. That was just my first approach to doing it and then I realized it would be shared by all the products. I also realized that I can't use a state, because it will be shared no matter what I do. I am new to this, so I was wondering whether there is a different approch I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `changeAmount` is changing a "global" amount value, which seems more like a total item count than anything else.

## Solution

The `amount` and `total` seem to be derived state, so they should just be computed when the `cart` is updated. I suggest you simply use the `addToCart` action to add a product and move the logic of determining if it's already in the cart into the reducer. Create a "cartItem" object to hold the product detail ***and*** the quantity.

Update the reducer function

```
const initialSate = {
  products: {},
  cart: [],
  total: 0,
}

export function productReducer(state = initialSate, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHANGE_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      }
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const item = action.payload;
      const isInCart = state.cart.some(({ id }) => id === item.id);

      let nextCart;
      if (isInCart) {
        nextCart = state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === item.id ? {
          ...cartItem,
          quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1,
        } : cartItem);
      } else {
        nextCart = [...state.cart, { ...item, quantity: 1 }];
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: nextCart,
        total: nextCart.reduce((total, { price, quantity }) => total + price * quantity, 0),
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now you have a cart state that includes the product details ***and*** a quantity, so the `amount` state isn't necessary.

Adjust your UI accordingly to display the item quantity when mapping the `cart` state in `Cart` instead of the passed `quantity` prop (*that is also no longer relevant*).

```
{!!cart && cart.length > 0 && cart.map(product => 
  <section key={product._id} >
    <h3>Productos en tu carrito</h3>
    <img src={product.productPictures} /> 
    <p>price={product.price * product.quantity}</p> // <-- update price computation
    <p>prodname={product.name}</p>
    <p>Cantidad:{product.quantity}</p> // <-- display product quantity
  </section>
)}
```